# Looping through nested directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new with angular and trying to do some directives nesting, but having some problems.

Here is my code :

```
module.controller("TimelineController", ["$scope", "$compile", function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.text = "ohoh";
    $scope.elements = ["12", "13"];

    console.log("Timeline Controller", arguments);

}]);

module.directive('timeline', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        controller : "TimelineController",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            console.log("linking timeline", arguments);
        },
        templateUrl:'templates/directives/timeline.html',
        replace: true
    };
});

module.directive('timelineEvent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        // controller : "TimelineController",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs/*, controller*/) {
            console.log("linking element", arguments);
        },
        templateUrl:'templates/directives/timeline_element.html',
        replace: false
    };
});
```

my templates :

timeline.html :

```
<div class="timeline">
    <p>
        timeline {{text}}
    </p>

    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
        - event {{element }}
        <timeline-event ng-model="{{element}}"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

timeline_element.html :

```
<div class="element">
    timeline element o/ \o
</div>
```

my index.html :

```
[...]
<body>

    <timeline></timeline>

</body>
```

And the unexpected result :

```
timeline ohoh

- event 12
- event 13
timeline element o/ \o
```

The expected result would be of course :

```
timeline ohoh

- event 12
timeline element o/ \o
- event 13
timeline element o/ \o
```

Why would the ng-repeat execute successfully, but the nested directive call only execute once? Is it not supposed to be able to use directives in loops?

Answer (score 3):

Three remarks. I don't know if these are the cause (need to test it in a jsFiddle for that), but they are surely breaking something:

- Why do you set `transclude: true`? You don't use `ng-transclude` in your template. You don't need `transclude: true`.
- the `ng-model` on your `timeline` should be `element` instead of `{{element}}`
- You are using `scope: true`, which means a new scope will be created. You probably will need to define your `scope` like (on both your directives).

Thus:

```
scope: {
   element: '&' // provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.
}
```

Comment: Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/fKbtt/).  It does what @asgoth suggested, except that you don't need to create a new scope, so the `scope: ` lines are commented out.

Comment: This example has a typo "ng-controlle", but it breaks without it, so weird!

Comment: That's really strange. It doesn't work if you bind the controller. WTF!?

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Rajcok please change following line to

```
<div ng-controlle="TimelineControllerCtrl">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="TimelineController">
```